Index or xlookup needed - looking to return multiple critera xlookup to same row
Thank you in advance for your assistance. Looking to do either a index/match formula or xlookup (open to any other solutions) to create this view in my sheet.
I am wanting excel to look at column N and retrieve the value of "vacation" and "prev. year vacation" and place it in cells U2 and V2. Its easy to get U2 over, but V2 needs to move up one cell and for all instances. You'll notice that row 6-7 does not have prev.year vacation so the formula will need to skip these rows or return "NA".
EDIT* I will also need it to reference the agent ID in column T so that the data will always belong to the correct ID.
Is this possible without VBA? enter image description here
I have tried index match formulas, and xlookup, however I am able to retrieve and place on the same row as the "prev. year vacation" I am unable to move that value up to the above row so I can then combine both totals for a combined total including current and previous years vacation.

Try these formulas
U2:  =IF(N2="Vacation",Q2,"")
V2:  =IF(AND(N2="Vacation",OFFSET(N2,1,0)="Prev. Year Vacation"),OFFSET(Q2,1,0),"")
and drag down.
Without OFFSET
V2:  =IF(AND(N2="Vacation",N3="Prev. Year Vacation"),Q3,"")
The OFFSET function takes the cell below and if the cell contains "Prev. Year Vacation" under "Vacation" then copy the value from column Q to the right of the actual cell.
